# Textual input to seeded random

Tags: javascript, random, theory, seeding

How would I take a textual input from the user (anything their keyboard would allow them to type), and transfer it to a number?

From there, I would probably take that number, and feed it into a seeded random number generator.

**I'm getting the idea from Minecraft's random seed option, but I can't find anything on it.**

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it in javascript, but when interacting with the keyboard what you're going to get are key codes. These will be integers. There are other things that are much more random however like the time interval between keystrokes and mouse movements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are probably more interesting algorithms but this just converts the characters to ints and multiplies it by the position in order to weight them (so that 'abc' is different than 'cba').  You could also use a hash function of some kind as well, but I thought that might be overkill for this purpose.
    ​

```js
var input = 'askljfhasjfh', num = 0;

for (var i = 0, len = input.length; i < len; ++i) {
  num += input.charCodeAt(i) * (i + 1);
}

console.log(num);
```

Keep in mind though, you can't seed the `Math.random()` function in Javascript, it always just uses the current date for the seed.

Comment: What's the *i part for? You're going to ignore the first character. Are you trying to do something like *Math.pow(2,3*i)?

Comment: I wasn't trying to be that fancy, though that would work as well. Just wanted to add a basic weight to the characters. I fixed it above so that I don't skip the first character.

Comment: You just made me realize how easily I overlooked that method o.o